# std::async: can we control the used thread pool?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, threadpool

When using `std::async`, tasks may be scheduled for a different thread to be executed.

But can we control anything about the number of threads that *can* be spawned underneath?  Or the priorities the tasks are to run in?  Or is this something for a library like Asio or the like?

Comment: Most of `std::async` is either unspecified or implementation-defined. I'd go with Boost if you want more control.